# Oracle 11g alternative options for oracle 12c with function

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query

I am using (with function) in Oracle 12c. in 11g this is not available. Is there any other way we can implement with function in 11g?

```
with 
  function x(p_NUM in number) return number
  is
    n number;
  begin
    SELECT 1 INTO N FROM DUAL;
    --
    return N;
    --
  end ; 
  --      
  function Y(p_NUM in number) return number
  is 
    N1 NUMBER;
  begin
    SELECT 2 INTO N1 FROM DUAL;
    --
    return N1;
    --
  end ; 
--
select X(1), Y(1)
from dual;
```

Comment: I think it depends what the functions does. if it's simple, then we have some options, some Oracle DBMS packages, built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

Create the functions within a `PACKAGE`.

Beyond that, you are using a feature that was introduced in 12c.